# Receive multipart file data in razor file

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have to create a razor file which Receive multipart file data and save it to a specific location.
I have done this before in an `.ashx` file. Like this

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            string fileNamePath = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(context.Request.Files[i].FileName) + "_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[i].FileName);
            string savePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/media/mm-signup-files/") + fileNamePath;
            context.Request.Files[i].SaveAs(savePath);

            context.Response.Write(fileNamePath + "|" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Files[i].FileName));


        }

    }

}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

but right Now I want to implement this code in a razor file. Is it possible to make it as razor?
I can't understand how to get `HttpContext` in a razor file with out implementing  `IHttpHandler` Interface. Or am I missing any thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpContext is a property of a Razor WebPage so you have access to Response and Request natively:

```
@{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            string fileNamePath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName) + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName);
            string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/media/mm-signup-files/") + fileNamePath;
            Request.Files[i].SaveAs(savePath);
            Response.Write(fileNamePath + "|" + Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the **Request** object in the action of controller and also you can access Request object in View, it is always accessible.